# Is $\mathcal{B}(L^p,L^1)$ strictly bigger than $L^q$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let  $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $1\leq q \leq \infty$. Denote by $p$  the conjugate exponent of $q$. We know, given a $g\in L^q (\Omega)$,
\begin{equation}
     T:f \in L^p(\Omega) \mapsto  gf 
\end{equation}
defines an element of $\mathcal{B}(L^p(\Omega),L^1(\Omega))$.
Moreover, by H"older's inequality,
we have $\|T\|\leq \|g\|_q$. Actually, if $q<\infty$, taking $f=|g|^{q-1}\in L^p(\Omega)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\|T\|\geq \frac{\|gf\|_1}{\|f\|_p} = \frac{\|g\|_q^q}{\|g\|_q^{q/p}} = \|g\|_q,
\end{equation}
thus, $\|T\|=\|g\|_q$; if $q=\infty$, considering the characteristic functions $f_n=\chi_{\{|g|\geq \|g\|_\infty- \frac{1}{n}\}}$ for those sufficiently large $n$'s, we also have
$\|T\|=\|g\|_\infty$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
g\mapsto T
\end{equation}
is an isometric embedding from $L^q(\Omega)$ to $\mathcal{B}(L^p(\Omega),L^1(\Omega))$. I guess
the  embedding is a surjective isometry. But I have difficulty verifying or disproving the statement. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Considering $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{R}^{\{1,\ldots,n\}}$ and $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with measure $\mu(j)=\tfrac1j$ will give you a simple counter example. In more general spaces, you can pobrably look at operators of the form $f\mapsto \int f(y)K(x,y)\mu(dy)$ with $K$ having some nice regularity conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most easily seen to be wrong for $p = 1$. In that case you are essentially asking if every operator from $L^1$ to $L^1$ is a multiplication operator, which is obviously not the case unless your measure space is very special. With this in mind, you can probably already see why this in wrong also for $p > 1$. To give an example, consider the counting measure on some finite set, say with $n$ elements. Then $\mathcal{B}(L^p, L^1)$ is equal to the set of $n \times n$ matrices. The elements you describe are exactly the diagonal matrices. But obviously there are more matrices than just the diagonal ones.

Answer (score 1):

This map can only be surjective in degenerate cases. Take $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$ with $0<\mu(A),\mu(B)<\infty$ and $\mu(A\cap B)=0$ (these may not exist, which is what I mean by "degenerate cases"). Let $E\subset L^q$ be the linear span of $1_A$. Since $E$ is finite-dimensional, there exists a closed subspace $F\subset L^p$ such that $L^p=E\oplus F$. Define $S\in B(L^p,L^1)$ in such a way that $S1_A=1_B$ and $S|_{F_q}=0$. Since $f1_A=0$ a.e. on $B$ for every $L^q$, there is no $f\in L^q$ such that $Sg=fg$ for all $g\in L^p$.